# For $x, y \in \Bbb R$ such that $(x+y+1)^2+5x+7y+10+y^2=0$. Show that $-5 \le x+y \le -2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

I have a problem:

> For $x, y \in \Bbb R$ such that $(x+y+1)^2+5x+7y+10+y^2=0$. Show that
>   $$-5 \le x+y \le -2.$$

I have tried:

I write $(x+y+1)^2+5x+7y+10+y^2=(x+y)^2+7(x+y)+(y+1)^2+10=0.$

Now I'm stuck :(

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x+y=c\iff y=c-x$

We have $(c+1)^2+5c+2y+10+y^2=0\iff y^2+2y+c^2+7c+11=0$

As $y$ is real, we need the discriminant $(2)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(c^2+7c+11)\ge0$

$\iff(c+2)(c+5)\le0$

Answer (score 3):

Since $(y+1)^2\ge 0$ we must have $(x+y)^2+7(x+y)+10=(x+y+5)(x+y+2)\leq 0$ then, solving this inequality for $x+y$, we get $$-5\le x+y \le -2$$